# Angularjs and Anti forgery token

Tags: angularjs, antiforgerytoken

How can we use Anti forgery token(CSRF) in angularjs application which is a standalone application not integrated with web api or mvc.

Comment: That is explained in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection. What don't you understand?

Comment: If your app is "not integrated with web api or mvc" it sounds like you don't need to worry about CSRF.

Comment: @JB Nizet- How will the token get refreshed ,since my ng application will be hosted different than my web api.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The token is automatically set as a header based on the XSRF cookie. It's up to you to set the cookie when you want to (typically after login)

Comment: With my understanding ,the token should get refreshed each time when web application makes request to server(correct me if im wrong),so how do we do it

Comment: No, that isn't necessary. What's the point?